# How to add Monaco font in Vim

Tags: vim, fonts, vim-plugin

I am trying to add [Monaco](https://github.com/cstrap/monaco-font) font in my vim but there are only few fonts available in my vim editor. How can I add [Monaco](https://github.com/cstrap/monaco-font) to vim?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's a fixed-width font? Code editors can't just use any old font ...

Comment: i am not sure about that but codeschool guys used that font in there ruby on rails series on vim..

Comment: Vim and Windows???? At least Ubuntu, rana sahib!

Comment: Agreed @ArslanAli but i have to configure everything on windows.

Comment: @RanaZubair The link you have provided, provides Monaco font for Unix based system. Are you sure you have installed the Monaco font on Windows?

Comment: Monaco is a font from Apple, installed by default in its OS X as a bitmap, monospaced font,and meant for code. Though it has been superceded by Menlo as the default code editing font, it still gets installed. **It is not a free font.**

Comment: no i don't install just check my font there is no monoco font...

Comment: But i surf on internet and people are suggesting to install it in ubuntu. it means if its out of the apple box then it must be available for windows...

Comment: problem solved i installed ttf font and then problem solved ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because font is not installed on the pc... If any one want to use Monaco font. He should make sure that Monaco font should be installed on his machine. Mac has by default Monaco installed but windows users and linux users have to install this font...

**First install the font then it will be available in all softwares**

Comment: Does not work for me. I have installed the Monaco ttf font onto windows, but it still does not show up with :set guifont=*

Comment: try installing some other fonts like otf, woff etc . Problem will be minor just look deeply into it. thanks

Comment: For info I solved it. If I remember correctly rebooting the computer solved it...

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same question. And Monaco is already installed in my PC. When I tried to use`:set guifont=Monaco:h12` in command mode, I got the following response. It seems as Vim doesn't recognize Monaco as a fixed pitch font.

[response of set guifont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROksD.png)